# When I run node, nothing happens, the same with forever

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, forever

I installed both node.js and forever.js and when I run them in my terminal (bash on Ubuntu 14.04), nothing happens.

So, it looks like:

```
#node
#
```

or

```
#forever
#forever --help
#forever listall
#
```

Everything else not node-related runs fine.

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: No error, it just goes to the next line, exactly like the blocks in the post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There was something wrong with `apt-get`, so when installing node, it didn't actually install node, but it did put a program in the path that did seemingly nothing.

I uninstalled it with

`apt-get purge node`

Then, I downloaded the 64-bit linux binary from here: http://nodejs.org/download/

And I extracted it with `tar -xvf filename`, then I set that `directory/bin` to the path with:

`PATH=$PATH:/directory/to/node/bin`

And now it works fine. The forever issue was because the node installed wasn't node at all, but instead a 30kb program of some sort, I don't know.

Here's the information about the program that was installed via `apt-get install node`:

```
Package: node
Priority: optional
Section: universe/hamradio
Installed-Size: 38
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Hamradio Maintainers <debian-hams@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Version: 0.3.2-7.4
Depends: ax25-node
Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
Filename: pool/universe/n/node/node_0.3.2-7.4_all.deb
Size: 1284
MD5sum: 7385a0f5916e03d9143459ca4706f0ec
SHA1: bf7aa087db81475636897ff39de344754ce1415b
SHA256: 9756770f771bcc4183cffa622f89e21a585be96bd4de27024b0a7cb167f310ad
Description-en: Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)
 The existing node package has been renamed to ax25-node. This transitional
 package exists to ease the upgrade path for existing users.
Description-md5: 1278ed271672fd829c99361f93f468da
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

So, I also found that the correct way to install `node` with `apt-get` is `apt-get install nodejs`.

Comment: Very strange, apt-get worked perfectly on a VM with the same Ubuntu image this afternoon but this worked perfectly as a fix for a clean full install.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, and I think it was caused because I naively apt-get installed node first.  Doing a

```
sudo apt-get purge node
```

Followed by the instructions on the web here (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

fixed the issue for me.  `node` doesn't exist, but `nodejs` does and other tools work (like `slap`) now.

EDIT: On one server I updated, node *did* exist.  Not sure exactly what order things need to happen in, but whatever...

Answer (score 8):

I was having this issue, I found that to solve the issue, I needed to remove the node file within /usr/sbin/node (found with `which node`) and replace it with a hard link to /usr/bin/nodejs (found with `which nodejs`)

`ln /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node`

Answer (score 3):

Just run `nodejs` command on your terminal after installing nodejs package.

It will give you the JavaScript prompt or interpreter.

Comment: That does work. However, I can't run a script with that, or use forever.

Comment: You could run `.js` files through `rhino`. Install it by running `sudo apt-get install rhino` command on your terminal.

Comment: I don't think `rhino` would support `socket.io` or filesystem readinging, would it? I have a script, albeit simple, that uses those. I'm considering moving to `Dart`, but it seems unnecessary as I've never had a problem with `node` before.

Comment: Create a link so that `node` runs your installed `nodejs` package: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that apt-get installed NodeJS under the binary nodejs. Also when you do a npm install forever -g it also expects the binary to be node.

To verify this you can do a

**% which forever**
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jan 25 21:34 /usr/local/bin/forever -> ../lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever

to find the location of the forever script.
Then check the node binary it's trying to execute.

**% vim /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever**
  #!/usr/bin/env node

This /usr/bin/env node needs to be changed to /usr/bin/env nodejs.

But to bypass this problem you should definitely look into using upstart. 
http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit